# Developing and Designing USB Software on Device and Computer

Tags: assembly, embedded, usb, hardware

> I'm not sure if this belongs here or on [Electrical Engineering](http://electronics.stackexchange.com),
>   but as its mostly software rather than the design, I think it belongs
>   here.

I am curious about developing a USB device similar to something I already have (Velleman K8055) which has a set of libraries and wrappers so that a program written in any number of languages can use the device simply.

My question is how to build a device driver on the computer, with tie-ins from other software. Also, if anyone knows any sources about developing the hardware device and the software for the embedded device so that it can properly identify itself to the computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Libusb is the normal choice for talking to USB devices.  It works on multiple platforms, and can be used from python using pyUSB.

Answer (score 0):

Someone has already done the hard work:

> http://www.obdev.at/products/vusb/prjdata.html
>
> http://www.obdev.at/products/vusb/projects.html